# Why is this an invalid cast?

Tags: c#, casting, combobox, enums, selecteditem

I'm populating a combo box with custom enum vals:

```
    private enum AlignOptions
    {
        Left,
        Center,
        Right
    }

. . .

    comboBoxAlign1.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(AlignOptions));
```

When I try to assign the selected item to a var of that enum type, though:

```
    AlignOptions alignOption;
. . .
    alignOption = (AlignOptions)comboBoxAlign1.SelectedItem;
```

...it blows up with: "*System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.*"

Isn't the item an AlignOptions type?

### UPDATE

Dang, I thought I was being clever. Ginosaji is right, and I had to change it to:

```
    alignOptionStr = comboBoxAlign1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (alignOptionStr.Equals(AlignOptions.Center.ToString()))
    {
        lblBarcode.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    }
    else if (alignOptionStr.Equals(AlignOptions.Left.ToString()))
    {
        . . .
```

Comment: In the debugger, can you verify that SelectedItem is actually what you think it is?

Comment: [`Enum.GetNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) returns `string[]`.

Comment: Responding OP's update: don't do this...you'll have to hardcode any change in the enum as well....use `Enum.GetValues` instead (see my answer about it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoul use [Enum.GetValues Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx#United%20States%20%28English%29) to initialize your combobox instead:

```
comboBoxAlign1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AlignOptions));
```

Now combobox contains the elements of the enum and

```
AlignOptions alignOption = (AlignOptions)comboBoxAlign1.SelectedItem;
```

is a correct cast.

Comment: Perfect! The answers sufficed as a workaround, but this is cleaner and more direct, I think.

Comment: This also allowed me to change this:

comboBoxFontSize1.SelectedIndex = comboBoxFontSize4.Items.IndexOf("Medium");

to this:

comboBoxFontSize1.SelectedItem = FontSizeType.Medium;

Answer (score 8):

It's an invalid cast because you do not have an enum, you have the string name representation of the enum. To get that enum back, you need to parse it.

```
alignOption = (AlignOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(AlignOptions), (string)comboBoxAlign1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: If I recall, `Enum.Parse` only accepts strings and the `SelectedItem` property returns an object. The combo box's selected item may need to be converted to a string first.

Comment: +1 this is insane I was about to google how to do this, then I saw a question from Clay so I check it out and its got the answer I was about to google. Talk about precognative!!

Answer (score 1):

`Enum.GetNames()` returns `string[]`, so each item is a `string`, not `AlignOptions`.

You can get the enum value by:

```
    alignOption = (AlignOptions) Enum.Parse(typeof(AlignOption), 
                                              (string) comboBoxAlign1.SelectedItem);
```

**References:**

- [Enum.GetNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx)
- [Enum.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)